# Task gets executed twice when a view runs first time

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I have pretty much the same configurations on my machine and on server but for some reason on server one of my tasks gets executed twice every time I run it.

Here's the task itself:

```
@shared_task
def send_congratulations_email(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    letter = MailLetter.objects.get(id=5)
    letter.send_letter({'{{USERNAME}}': user.name}, user.email)
```

And here's part of my view where I add this task to queue:

```
if self.kwargs['action'] == 'confirm':
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
    send_congratulations_email.delay(user_id=user.pk)
```

As I can see in logs, celery worker is receiving this task twice:

```
[2014-11-24 07:06:42,901: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: users.tasks.send_congratulations_email[9b04709b-52ae-4602-8f38-1bebb40986b9]
[2014-11-24 07:06:43,103: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: users.tasks.send_congratulations_email[3138895a-4efb-438d-a20f-c71d42e50b64]
```

I've also noticed that it happens only the first time I click the url that points to specific view. After that, when I open the same url, there's only one task that gets executed.

By the way, I use Redis as message broker. Maybe that could be the problem. But I use Redis on my development machine too, and there's no such problem there.

Comment: maybe it need some additional recourses and send second request to your view, put `print` somewhere in your view